# Best software to manage programs?

Tags: jira, program-management

My company is starting a new program that will consist of many projects:

- An Android application
- An iOS application
- A web application
- A backend to support the applications
- A business analysis
- A brand strategy
- etc...

We have been using Jira for years but we are now wondering how we could use Jira to manage that program.

What we need is, obviously, to manage releases by project, and to give the Project Manager a way to follow the program iself in a concise and consolidated way.

Can Jira provide that? Do you have any other recommandation?

Comment: Hi Eric MORAND, welcome. Questions about software recommendations are off-topic here... use [Software Recs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 thanks for the heads up. I wasn't aware of Software Recs. I'll post my question there. :)

Comment: Questions about software recommendation are offtopic in PM.SE, as mentioned in comments.

Answer (score 2):

What we do in our projects is create separate Quick Filters with the Epic Link for each projects in the JIRA Board. So, individuals involved in a single project can filter out the tickets. Project Manager can overlook the whole program status by not selecting any specific filter which will ultimately show all the tickets on the board.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Jira is a grand tool, but also please check out the venerable ***Microsoft Project.®***

MS-Project is extremely good at helping you to break down projects into smaller pieces which have ***dependencies*** on each other.  It is also very good at handling "separate" projects which have dependencies – which surely will be your company's case here.

It's a complementary tool to Jira, and, as far as I am concerned, it is "second to none" for what it does.  As far as I know, Microsoft Corporation developed it - legend has it that it started as Excel spreadsheets – for its own use.  Thousands of customers have used it since.  (And, IMHO, "no open-source alternative even comes close.")

As you might well have guessed, "I swear by (and sometimes, swear at ...) MS-Project."

Answer (score 0):

Recently JIRA has launched the roadmaps. I use it to map the product roadmap items in my program and in turn use components to indicate platforms - iOS, Android etc.

It gives me a high level picture of where we are in the program for each of the items on product roadmap.

I wish there was a kind of hierarchical structure in JIRA though so we could link separate projects to make a program board.

Hope this helps